# Which process binder driver runs in?

Tags: android, android-binder

I know binder is Android IPC mechanism. If a process A communicates with a process B by binder, transaction data flow through binder driver which create `binder_node` in the process A and create `binder_ref` in the process B respectively in kernel memory. So I have a doubt : which process binder driver runs in? Is it a system process?

Answer (score 1):

The binder driver is part of the kernel; it does not run in a userspace process.

Certain userspace processes interact with the binder driver directly via `/dev/binder`, namely `servicemanager` and the native Binder Framework libraries that are part of the application runtime.